# How to change the background colour in the Material Preview window?

Tags: materials

If I want to change the colour of the sphere in the Material Preview Window, it's easy enough to create a Material Output node, Create a shader node, assign a colour and hook them up. The sphere colour changes accordingly.

But how do I change the colour of what's in the background, behind the sphere?

Moreover, what does that colour represent? In my example it's Magenta and I don't know why.

[image: what does the magenta colour represent]

Comment: Usually there is a checkerboard pattern behind the sphere. And that looks like the color that usually indicates a missing texture in the 3D viewport. I don't really know but It makes me think you are missing that image somehow.

Comment: It seems that I somehow chose a colour (or texture?) in Blender that is impossible to display.  The same magenta colour shows up in GIMP when selecting an impossible colour combination, as per this answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/125622/when-i-try-to-change-a-color-everything-become-purple