# How can I change the background of the material preview?

Tags: materials, interface

I wonder if it is somehow possible to change the background of the material preview window in **Blender 3.2**.

The default setting shows a checkerboard pattern on a grid:

[image]

And I found the question here, of course: [How to change the background colour in the Material Preview window?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196402)

But apart from the fact that this question has not been answered either, this is obviously a different problem.

I would have liked to use a custom scenery there (For example a photo studio wall with a soft edge, and a different base texture and viewed from a different angle).

Here I have found another interesting question/answer about this, in which you can see what I want to achieve, but this does not solve my problem: [Material preview background color - Blender Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109550)

Is this possible (without modifying the source code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preview scenes are defined by the [`preview.blend`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/preview.blend) file, which is included in the compiled binary (not as a separate file). As far as I'm aware, Blender's preferences and Python API do not provide an option to modify the scenes. It appears you would have to build Blender yourself with an adapted [`preview.blend`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/preview.blend).

The current version of the material preview, at the time of writing, was introduced in the following commit: https://developer.blender.org/rBf5ea1fc4fbafbac6f648ba0d9d9ef16ca8323041

Comment: OK, I see, that's what I was afraid of. So I take the answer as "No, it's not possible without changing the source and compiling Blender.". Thanks!